# OAuth 2.0 Authentication screen stays open

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

Quick question that has be baffled.

I'm following the examples from I/O '12 ( [link](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/blob/master/io-2012-demos/authSample.html) ) and I got it working but for some reason after I grant access, the window goes to a white screen, the title says "Connecting..." and stays there.  There are no errors in the console, and I'm good to go as far as the OAuth authentication is concerned.

I want to point out that I'm doing this inside a Chrome extension's popup using a [page action](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction).  I don't know if that makes any difference.

The demo of that sample works great so I'm thinking it has something to do with being inside a chrome extension.  I just can't figure out what it could be.  [demo](https://google-api-javascript-client.googlecode.com/hg/samples/authSample.html)

The code I'm using is pretty much identical to the sample:

**js/oauth/oauth.js:**

```
  var clientId = '[MY_CLIENTID]';
  var apiKey = '[MY_API_KEY]';
  var scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me';

  // Use a button to handle authentication the first time.
  function handleClientLoad() {
    gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);
    window.setTimeout(checkAuth,1);
  }
  function checkAuth() {
    gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: true}, handleAuthResult);
  }
  function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
    var authorizeButton = document.getElementById('authorize-button');
    var flows = document.getElementById('flows');
    var welcome = document.getElementById('welcome');

    if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
      flows.style.display = 'none';
      welcome.style.display = '';
      makeApiCall();
    } else {
      flows.style.display = '';
      welcome.style.display = 'none';
      authorizeButton.onclick = handleAuthClick;
    }
  }
  function handleAuthClick(event) {
    gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: false}, handleAuthResult);
    return false;
  }
  // Load the API and make an API call.  Display the results on the screen.
  function makeApiCall() {
    gapi.client.load('plus', 'v1', function() {
      var request = gapi.client.plus.people.get({
        'userId': 'me'
      });
      request.execute(function(resp) {
        var heading = document.createElement('p');
        var image = document.createElement('img');
        image.src = resp.image.url;

        var welcometext = document.createTextNode("Welcome ");
        var welcometextend = document.createTextNode(", you are now logged in!");

        heading.appendChild(welcometext);
        heading.appendChild(document.createTextNode(resp.displayName));
        heading.appendChild(welcometextend);

        document.getElementById('content').appendChild(heading);

        document.getElementById('avatar').appendChild(image);
      });
    });
  }
```

**popup.html:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="js/oauth/oauth.js"></script>
        <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=handleClientLoad"></script>
    </head>


<body style="width: 500px">

<div id="flows" style="display: none;" >
  <h2>Please log in before starting</h2>
    <button id="authorize-button">Log in</button>

</div>  

<div id="welcome" style="display: none;">
<div id="avatar"></div>
<div id="content"></div>

</div>


 </body>
</html>
```

sdlkfad

This is what it looks like:
[image: OAuth White Screen]

Comment: _"inside a Chrome extension's popup using a content script"_ Sorry, what?

Comment: @Xan Sorry I confused that part.  It's actually a page action of a Chrome extension that loads a popup.html file that does the OAuth. https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction

Comment: Instead of a very, er, _informative_ screenshot you should include relevant code in the question itself.

Comment: @Xan I've edited the post to include my code.  Thanks for the help so far!